# Eclipse CDT not launching executable

Tags: eclipse, executable, eclipse-cdt

I've been using MinGW, no real problems until Eclipse decides it doesn't want to run the executables any more. The run config is still the same, the project builds 100% fine, and I can run the built executable from command line/GUI. The console in Eclipse is empty, save for  on the top bar followed by the executable name and time/date.

Just made a hello world project from the menu, same thing happens to it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error, and here is what I did:

Proper binary parser must be selected so Eclipse can recognize the executable: Select the project, then right click.

**Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Binary Parsers, PE Windows Parser** (or you can select Cygwin if you use that compiler, on Linux I use Elf parser.).

That worked for me at least for Cross compiler (both on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04)